# Referencing in lambda - java

Tags: java

I have created a class named `Player` and a class named `Car` , which has a method called  `isOwner(Player player)`. It has a constructor that is like this:

```java
public Car(String name, Action<Player> action) {
        this.name=name;
        this.action = action;
}
```

Now in my main code I want to do this:

```
Car car1 = new Car("BMW", (input ->{
            if (this.isOwner(input)){
                // code 
            }
           }));
```

But here `this` references the class I am writing inside (e.g. `Main` class); also if I put `car1` instead of `this`, it will give error saying car1 may not be initialized.

Comment: what you're trying to do is not possible in the way you're trying to do it: the lambda needs to be fully initialized before you can pass it to the Car constructor. I'd recommend amending your `Action`  interface so that it passes the car object as well as a second parameter

Comment: The lambda is created before your `car1` variable is assigned to. Further, it is possible (and Java cant prove that you perhaps dont) that the `Car` class invokes the lambda already in its constructor (so before `car1` is assigned).

Answer (score 3):

I would go for a good old-fashioned unfashionable anonymous inner class.

```
Car car1 = new Car("BMW") {
    @Override protected action(Player input) {
        if (isOwner(input)) {
            // code 
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Excellent answer. One of the things that makes Java powerful is that new advancements do not overwrite the old (completely) - they complement them. This is an instance where using a lambda (or trying to force one in) would be inferior to just using an Anonymous Class.

Answer (score 2):

You should use an abstract class for that:

```java
public abstract class Car {

    private final String name;

    public Car(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean isOwner(Player player) {
        // impl
    }

    public abstract action(Player player);
}
```

And then create a new instance of `Car` with a custom implementation of the `action` method using [anonymous class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html):

```java
Car car1 = new Car("car1") {
    @Override
    public void action(Player player) {
        if (this.isOwner(player)) {
            // code
        }
    }
};
```